# How to add a page in notebook dynamically Odoo/OpenERP?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

How can I use the onchange event in a many2one field to add/remove a page in notebook dynamically, I have tried using the function `fields_view_get` but only runs when loading the view not on the onchange event.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a related field and write the right condition in the `attrs`attribute in the page.

```python
related_field = fields.Char(
    string='Related field',
    related='many2one_id.name',
    store=False,
)
```

```xml
<field name="related_field" invisible="1" />

<page string="Title" attrs="{'invisible': [('related_field','=','Element name')]}">
    ...
</page>
```

Or if you condition is more complex you can use an onchange function like this

```python
field_name = fields.Char(
    string='Field name',
)

@api.one
@api.onchange('many2one_id')
def onchange_many2one_id(self):
    # [...]
    self.field_name = 'hidden'
```

But you need an `attrs` attribute in the view as well

```xml
<field name="field_name" invisible="1" />

<page string="Title" attrs="{'invisible': [('field_name','=', 'hidden')]}">
    ...
</page>
```

I think you can develop what you want with these advices.

Comment: thank you very much, this example can serve me but I want to know how to do it dynamically to show / hide the page from the Python code, for example using the function fields_view_get

Comment: `fields_view_get()` is called whenever tree or form is opened. It doesn't depend on create or write functions. I'm not sure if you can do what you want to do with that function.

Comment: It's true, I was reviewing how to use just this function, but only runs when you open a tree or form view as you explain me, I was thinking maybe I can inherit the view to edit and use Qweb templates to add the new page, it may be this possible?

Comment: Maybe you can inherit and override the right widgets in JavaScript and do what you want to do. But I'm still thinking the best you can do is what I suggested, faster and easier.